# Allowing Multi-Touch within different iFrames using Pointer Events

Tags: javascript, html

Here's the scenario: I have two iFrames setup. Within those iFrames I have different button links that go to various web pages. The Tablet is setup so that two users can navigate websites within their half of the tablet screen.

When user1 is actively touching the screen, either within the containing div or on a button, I want user2 to be able to click their buttons / links.

In my research, I have found hints, that pointer events may allow me to track the various pointerIDs and to handle them accordingly but no examples.

How can I achieve this with JavaScript?